# Getting Wowhead tooltips to function in Excel spreadsheet through Javascript

Tags: javascript, excel, world-of-warcraft

I am trying to use the instructions at https://www.wowhead.com/tooltips to integrate tooltips through JS to my spreadsheet. The script provided by the website is attached below. I want to be able to use the item codes they use to visually show what the items are when compiling gear lists. An example item code would be [item=14145] pulling from their website to generate the proper tooltip.

How would I properly load that into Excel to utilize the item codes?

```
<script>var whTooltips = {colorLinks: true, iconizeLinks: true, renameLinks: true};</script>
<script src="https://wow.zamimg.com/widgets/power.js"></script>
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you've done so far?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tdKUKUqoT901t_qzkNcYQYWmBqScBe5O/view?usp=sharing

Comment: If you download it and open with excel, each item has a modified tooltip that I hand-made with the comment ability. I would LOVE to be able to just use the tooltips provided by WowHead so they show current information and I dont have to make them manually. I still have another 1,500 or so items to put in there and it's pretty time consuming.